# discord.py - How to make bot events still work after my discord bot restarts?

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm making a logging system for my Discord bot. Everything works perfectly fine. There's one small problem with it though: If my bot restarts, the previous messages will not be logged. The messages are only able to be logged is after the bot starts. This is a **major** problem as it's not logging older messages. Does anyone know how to make this event still work for older messages (**after the bot restarts**) for it to work? Please and thanks.

### Full code for sending logs:

```
@bot.event
async def on_member_remove(member):
                with open("database\\database_main\\serverdb.json", encoding="utf-8") as f:
                    data = json.load(f)
                if str(member.guild.id) in data:
                    logera = data[str(member.guild.id)]['log_leavelogs']
                    if logera == 0:
                        with open("database\\database_main\\serverdb.json", encoding="utf-8") as f:
                            data = json.load(f)
                        if str(member.guild.id) in data:
                            isenabled = data[str(member.guild.id)]['logchlID']
                            if isenabled == 0:
                                return
                            else:
                                channelrs = bot.get_channel(data[str(member.guild.id)]['logchlID'])
                                embed = discord.Embed(title=f"Member Left", color=discord.Colour.red())
                                embed.set_footer(text=f"User ID: {member.id}")
                                embed.set_author(name=f"{member.display_name} (@{member.name})", icon_url=member.avatar)
                                await channelrs.send(embed=embed)


@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
                with open("database\\database_main\\serverdb.json", encoding="utf-8") as f:
                    data = json.load(f)
                if str(member.guild.id) in data:
                    logera = data[str(member.guild.id)]['log_joinlogs']
                    if logera == 0:
                        with open("database\\database_main\\serverdb.json", encoding="utf-8") as f:
                            data = json.load(f)
                        if str(member.guild.id) in data:
                            isenabled = data[str(member.guild.id)]['logchlID']
                            if isenabled == 0:
                                return
                            else:
                                creation = member.created_at.strftime("%a %#d %B %Y, %I:%M %p")
                                channelrs = bot.get_channel(data[str(member.guild.id)]['logchlID'])
                                embed = discord.Embed(title=f"Member Joined", color=discord.Colour.green())
                                embed.add_field(name="Account Creation Date", value=f"{creation}")
                                embed.set_footer(text=f"User ID: {member.id}")
                                embed.set_author(name=f"{member.display_name} (@{member.name})", icon_url=member.avatar)
                                await channelrs.send(embed=embed)
                    else:
                        return


@bot.event
async def on_member_ban(guild, user):
    async for entry in guild.audit_logs(limit=1,action=discord.AuditLogAction.ban):
            with open("database\\database_main\\serverdb.json", encoding="utf-8") as f:
                data = json.load(f)
            if str(user.guild.id) in data:
                logera = data[str(guild.id)]['log_banlogs']
                if logera == 0:
                    with open("database\\database_main\\serverdb.json", encoding="utf-8") as f:
                        data = json.load(f)
                    if str(guild.id) in data:
                        isenabled = data[str(user.guild.id)]['logchlID']
                        if isenabled == 0:
                            return
                        else:
                            channelrs = bot.get_channel(data[str(guild.id)]['logchlID'])
                            embed = discord.Embed(title=f"Member Banned", description=f"", color=discord.Colour.red())
                            embed.add_field(name="Banned by", value=f"{entry.user.mention}")
                            embed.add_field(name="Reason", value=f"{entry.reason}")
                            embed.set_author(name=f"{entry.target.display_name} (@{entry.target})", icon_url=user.avatar)
                            embed.set_thumbnail(url=user.avatar)
                            await channelrs.send(embed=embed) 

@bot.event
async def on_message_edit(message_before, message_after):
        with open("database\\database_main\\serverdb.json", encoding="utf-8") as f:
            data = json.load(f)
        if str(message_before.guild.id) in data:
            if message_before.content == message_after.content:
                return
            else:
                logera = data[str(message_before.guild.id)]['log_editedmsglogs']
                if logera == 0:
                    with open("database\\database_main\\serverdb.json", encoding="utf-8") as f:
                        data = json.load(f)
                    if str(message_before.guild.id) in data:
                        isenabled = data[str(message_before.guild.id)]['logchlID']
                        if isenabled == 0:
                            return
                        else:
                            if not message_before.content == "":
                                channelrs = bot.get_channel(data[str(message_before.guild.id)]['logchlID'])
                                embed = discord.Embed(title=f"Message by @{message_before.author.name} edited in {message_before.channel.mention}", description=f"**Before**\n{message_before.content}\n**After**\n{message_after.content}", color=discord.Colour.blue())
                                embed.set_author(name=f"{message_before.author.display_name} (@{message_before.author.name})", icon_url=message_before.author.avatar)
                                embed.add_field(name="Jump to Message", value=f"[Click here to jump to message]({message_before.jump_url})")
                                embed.set_thumbnail(url=message_before.author.avatar)
                                await channelrs.send(embed=embed) 
        else:
            return

@bot.event
async def on_message_delete(message):
    async for entry in message.guild.audit_logs(limit=1,action=discord.AuditLogAction.message_delete):
        deleter = entry.user
        with open("database\\database_main\\serverdb.json", encoding="utf-8") as f:
            data = json.load(f)
        if str(message.guild.id) in data:
            logera = data[str(message.guild.id)]['log_deletemsglogs']
            if logera == 0:
                with open("database\\database_main\\serverdb.json", encoding="utf-8") as f:
                    data = json.load(f)
                if str(message.guild.id) in data:
                    isenabled = data[str(message.guild.id)]['logchlID']
                    if isenabled == 0:
                        return
                    else:
                        if not message.content == "":
                            channelrs = bot.get_channel(data[str(message.guild.id)]['logchlID'])
                            embed = discord.Embed(title=f"Message by @{message.author.name} deleted in {message.channel.mention}", description=f"**Message Contents**\n{message.content}", color=discord.Colour.red())
                            embed.set_author(name=f"{message.author.display_name} (@{message.author.name})", icon_url=message.author.avatar)
                            embed.set_thumbnail(url=message.author.avatar)
                            await channelrs.send(embed=embed)       
            else:
                return
```

Please let me know if you need more information, and I will gladly provide it :)

EDIT:

If you are having trouble trying to identify what Issue I'm facing, here you go:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bC8Nvva2w2f6GAmMZOanxgD7C3BFtD5U/view?usp=sharing
(mp4 file)

Answer (score 1):

If you loss all your data in the json file after you restart your bot, I am sorry to tell that this is a common issue that I have faced for several times also.
There is no direct solution to the issue because the issue is caused by the IO process of json file. There is no problem with your code. However to play safe you should consider adding a background task for backup.

Here is my bg task for backup:

```
import asyncio
import json
import traceback 

async def backup():
    print('Log Auto BackUp successful started.')
    while True:
        for i in range(4):
            try:
                with open(f'your json file', 'r')as jfile:
                    jdata = json.load(jfile)
                with open(f'your_path/log_copy{i+1}.json', 'w')as jfile:
                    json.dump(jdata, jfile, indent=4)
            except:
                traceback.print_exc() 
            await asyncio.sleep(450)
    

asyncio.run(backup())
```

You can either run it directly in another terminal, or pack it inside your bot.
If you pack it inside your bot, you have to add a few lines like this to replace `bot.run('your token')`:

```
loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
loop.create_task(asyncio.run(backup()))
loop.create_task(bot.run('your token')
loop.run_forever()
```

This task will not conflict with your bot and will copy your json file into 4 different json files for backup every 450s.
Therefore once you loss you data, you can at least restore most data.

Comment: Unfortunately, thats not my problem. I edited my question to further state what issue I'm facing.

Comment: But your idea for automatically saving JSON files helps! I already have one and its a pain to manually save it.

Comment: One problem: The script doesn't continue after the backup is ran. I've tried everything to fix this strange issue... Do you know a fix?

Comment: I am sorry that I made a mistake up there. If you wanna pack it inside your bot you may have to add some codes.
I forgot to mention that to run more than one asyncio script at once, you have to create tasks  for each of them.
I will modify the answer above to give you more details.

Comment: And by the way I think I know what your issue is, so the bot fail to record the first message after it restarts right

Comment: I will later make another answer when I am free and understand more to your situation.

Comment: yes thats the issue

Comment: @As2Bax I am sorry even I have met this before but I am not sure why there is such issue, and didn't found any way to solve this issue.